# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Grails after database import

Tags: mysql, grails, load-data-infile

I've imported some data from CSV file to MYSQL database. The data is imported properly. But then I run my application corresponding to that database, it gives `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on each Domain related method. 
For example

```
Contacts contact = Contacts.get(id);
Contacts.count(), etc
```

Here I checked if it is getting `id` properly as well as checked the database with the same `id`. Database has the record with same `id`. But in grails application it gives `IllegalArgumentException`. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the domain class source code with us?

Comment: @defectus : I've imported data for 3 domains actually. And all 3 of them gives this exception. Can't share domain for security purpose.

Answer (score 2):

the `IllegalArgumentException` I was getting was not enough to understand the problem. So I turned on Hibernate Logging and then understood the problem. I had some primitive type of fields in the domain, in which the `NULL` value was stored while loading CSV file. Due to which I got the above exception.